# How does React-Router work?

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using express and trying to implement partial pieces of react as sort of a demo. But one react component renders separately on a different page while the rest render on one. I assume react router is perfect this since I can route the page to the component so only one component will render if on that page.

Index.jsx

```
import { Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

var Projects = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className ="project-page">
       <Change />
       <Mortgage />
       <Todo />
       <Astro />
     </div>
   );
  }
});
var Landing = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className ="landing-page">
        <App />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var MyApp = React.createClass ({
render: function(){
  return(
   <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
   <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
   </Router>
  );
 }
});
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('output'))

export default index;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jmargolisvt It doesn't load any react components at all when i include the route tag

Comment: what is `history` in your code? undefined? also that's not the correct api for react-router-dom. you're using the v3 api. check here for v4: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: also what is `index`?

Comment: @azium sorry I am really new to this, I just added the history from an example and assumed that was just part of react-router-dom. As for the second question, index is the index.jsx I am exporting to my entry point to my webpack index.js

Comment: I suggest creating a project using facebook's official `create-react-app` and see how they do it. looks like you're missing some fundamental knowledge